# Sliding Horizontal divs in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a sliding div module which is controlled by 'left' and 'right' buttons on either side of the wrapper div, but I'm having some trouble with figuring out the best way to do so.

The HTML structure of this module is like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
                <div class="scrollLeft">
                    <span>Left</span>
                </div>
                <div class="scrollingDivs">
                    <div class="scrollThis">Some content</div>
                    <div class="scrollThis">different content</div>
                    <div class="scrollThis">more content</div>
                    <div class="scrollThis">even more content</div>
                    <div class="scrollThis">and more content</div>
                </div>
                <div class="scrollRight">
                    <span>Right</span>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

The corresponding CSS looks like this:

```
.wrapper{
width: 720px;
float: left;
height: 146px;
position: relative;
}
.scrollLeft, .scrollRight{
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 130px;
text-indent: -99999px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.scrollLeft{
background: url('../img/left.png') no-repeat;
float: left;
margin-right: 16px;
}
.scrollRight{
background: url('../img/right.png') no-repeat;
float: right;
}
.scrollLeft:hover{
background: url('../img/left-hl.png') no-repeat;
}
.scrollRight:hover{
background: url('../img/right-hl.png') no-repeat;
}
.scrollingDivs{
width: 672px;
margin-left: 28px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 146px;
}
.scrollThis{
display: inline-block;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(65,65,66,0.3);
border-top: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
width: 160px;
height: 140px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: -8px;
line-height: 16px;
left: 0;
}
```

There's a bit more to it, but that's the basic gist of it.

So when scrollLeft is clicked, the scrollThis divs should go slightly transparent and move to the left - the first ones should go out of sight, and the ones more to the right should pop into sight. Ideally, I would also check to be sure that if the scrolled divs are at either end that another effect happens instead (maybe the scrollLeft arrow glows or something).

So I began on the JQuery for this but ran into an early issue of how to actually get them to move. Because of the way that this is all set up, doing an animate with left-=50 doesn't seem to work. Here's what I have for that so far, though it's rudimentary right now at best. This is just testing on the 'click left' portion'.

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scrollLeft').click(function(){
        $('.scrollThis').animate({
            opacity: '0.25',
            left: '-=50'
            }, 500, 'linear', function(){});    
        });
    });
  </script>
```

What happens in my testing is that the opacity will fade, yes, and the divs will all receive -=50 to the left property, but they don't move. How should I better structure the JS or CSS to get the desired effect?

Thanks

Comment: First, this: text-indent: -99999px;  Hides the clickable span.  Please make a jsFiddle.

Comment: Yes, I know - that's mostly just filler to make the divs always appear. I'll try to make a jsFiddle later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great plugin for this - jCarousel. It needed some pretty heavy skinning, but minor customization from my part to get it to work beautifully. http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Answer (score 0):

What if you animate the container?  It seems to make things move:

```
$('.scrollingDivs').animate({
```

Comment: That moves the whole thing, yeah, but that's not particularly helpful. The point is that the first one in the list becomes hidden - giving the illusion that its sliding under (paper under cutout effect). Though - I suppose I could wrangle a solution using just z-indexes..potentially.

Comment: If you just want to hide the first div, use hide:  http://api.jquery.com/hide/  It animates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am all for learning, but why reinvent the wheel when you can utilise something like this?

Cycle Plugin is extremely flexible and can do everything plus more that you want.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Cycle is cool, but isn't so useful for moving multiple images at once. I found a much better solution - jCarousel. I'll answer this question myself.